# Как при регистрации User-А реализовать создание нового BitCoin кошелька?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, bitcoin

Коллеги, подскажите, как реализовать создание нового BitCoin-кошелька для пользователя при регистрации на сайте? Интересует, есть ли уже готовые сторонние сервисы? Платформа Nodejs. Вопрос в том, что даже нет вообще представления с чего начать и в какую сторону смотреть...

Comment: Что значит новый кошелек для пользователя? Вам нужно принимать платежи в биткоинах?

Comment: Да да..........

Comment: В Bitcoin Core клиенте есть RPC команда GetNewAddress. Один из вариантов

Comment: Благодарю.. Ща гляну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Для начала установим модули*

**npm install bitcore-lib --save**

и скачиваем список слов **words.json** - если прогуглить, то можно найти.

Выглядит  приблизительно так:

```
[
  "abandon",
  "ability",
  "able",
  "about",
  "above",
  "absent",
  "absorb",
  "abstract"
  ...
```

Теперь подключаем модуль и список **words.json** к проекту (я переместил данный файл words.json в директорию resources)

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib'), 
    words = require('../resources/words');
```

После создаем переменную с пустым массивом

```
var resWords = [];
```

и добавляем в этот массив список из случайных слов (в данном случае будет 30 слов)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  resWords.push(words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]);
}
```

добавляем все в свои данные

```
data.wallet = {};

data.wallet.passphrase = resWords.join(' ');
```

создаем буфер, хэшируем и оптимизируем все это

```
var buffer = new Buffer(data.wallet.passphrase),
    hash = bitcore.crypto.Hash.sha256(buffer),
    bn = bitcore.crypto.BN.fromBuffer(hash);
```

далее создаем приватный ключ и кошелек и сохранить все в нашем объекте

```
data.wallet.privateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey(bn).toWIF();

data.wallet.address = new bitcore.PrivateKey(bn).toAddress();
```

сохраняем

```
var user = new User(data);

user.save(callback);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобится запущенный где-то (возможно, на локальной по отношению к node.js машине) bitcoind и настроенная авторизация для API-доступа к нему.

Дальше просто: при заведении нового пользователя создаёте новый адрес в кошельке (getnewaddress) и привязываете полученный адрес к пользователю своими средствами. Это не входит в функционал bitcoind, хотя минимальные средства для разделения учётных записей в него встроены: тот же параметр `account` в вызове `getnewadddress` и множество вызовов, где он *может* быть использован. Обратите внимание, что во всех вызовах, где может быть передан параметр `account`, он помечен как "DEPRECATED". Так что лучше всего сразу завести у себя табличку один-ко-многим и вести соответствие набора адресов пользователям там.

Comment: Вопрос уже решен.... Может чуть позже оформлю ответ